# The code runs well but I'm a beginner and I want to make it more user friendly just out of curiosity.... How to make it more user friendly?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i, n;
    long sum=0;
    
    puts("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        
        sum = sum + (i * i);

        printf("(%d * %d) = %d\n", i, i, (i*i) );

    }

    printf("\nThe sum of the series is %ld\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

suppose I enter the input as 5, then the operation goes like this 1 * 1 = 1, 2 * 2 = 4, 3 * 3 = 9, 4 * 4 = 16, 5 * 5 = 25..... and then, I want to show the sum of every individual product...
I want the output to be like this:

(1 * 1) = 1

(2 * 2) = 4

(3 * 3) = 9

(4 * 4) = 16

(5 * 5) = 25

The sum of the series is **1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25** = **55**

Comment: What is your understanding of what "user friendly" means?

Comment: I mean if I run the program, then I want to see the sum of every individual product here as I mentioned I want to print it like this, then how should I write the code?

Comment: Azhar, robust code validates input first.  Did `scanf()` return a 1? Was input non-numeric (and if so, was it consumed)? Was `n` in a sane range?  If not, a friendly error message should occur.  Any code can be nice when things are right, how about when input is bad?  How about better directions than `"Enter the number: "`?

Comment: Is the problem the last output line? You can either write another loop that repeats the calculations and prints the expected output or store the intermediate results in an array.

Comment: chug-Reinstate Monica, I am a beginner and not so good yet. You can suggest me a better direction. I would be thankful to you if you can tell me where is my input bad... But when I ran the program, it did the job but I want to print the sum of every individual squares and then print the final sum of all the squares

Comment: kaylum, Can you please write the code here?? I am unable to figure it out properly and please don't use array. I am not yet very familiar with arrays

Answer (score 2):

For a start, you can do it in the loop itself:

```
printf("\nThe sum of the series is ");
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    sum = sum + (i * i);
    
    // Don't print a leading + for the first number to avoid
    // "The sum of the series is + 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 = 55"
    if (i > 1) {
        printf(" + ");
    }

    // Print the current term
    printf("%d", i * i);
}
printf(" = %ld\n", sum);
```

This outputs, for

- n = 2:

```
The sum of the series is 1 + 4 = 5
```

- n = 5:

```
The sum of the series is 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 = 55
```

But it also outputs, for

- n = 0:

```
The sum of the series is  = 0
```

- n = 1:

```
The sum of the series is 1 = 1
```

Handling user input is up to you.

---

If you also wants to output the middle terms, you can iterate over the terms twice:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    sum = sum + (i * i);
    printf("(%d * %d) = %d\n", i, i, i*i);
}
    
printf("The sum of the series is ");
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    if (i > 1) printf(" + ");
    printf("%d", i*i);
}
printf(" = %ld.\n", sum);
```

Outputs

```
(1 * 1) = 1
(2 * 2) = 4
(3 * 3) = 9
(4 * 4) = 16
(5 * 5) = 25
The sum of the series is 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 = 55.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at your requirements.

I saved every product in its own array during the loop, then print them one by one again in the final line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned i, n; // no negative numbers used
    long unsigned sum = 0;
    long unsigned parcel[2000]; // could use VLA or dynamic memory

    printf("Enter the number: ");      // write the input on the
    fflush(stdout);                    // same line as the prompt

    if (scanf("%u", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input error.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (n > 2000) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, max number is 2000.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { // I like to start for loops at 0
        long unsigned product = (i + 1) * (i + 1);
        sum = sum + product;
        printf("(%u * %u) = %lu\n", i + 1, i + 1, product);
        // save product for final output
        parcel[i] = product;
    }

    printf("\nThe sum of the series is %lu", parcel[0]);
    // exception for starting for loops at 0: the 0th element was printed above
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" + %lu", parcel[i]);
    printf(" = %lu\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a few things you could do just as a suggestion for beginner legibility

```
sum = sum + (i * i);
```

`i*i` can be pulled out to

```
int iSquared = i * i;
```

then store

```
int nextProduct = sum + iSquared;
```

and finally simplify the summation with

```
sum += nextProduct
```

Bringing it all together you'd have

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i, n;
    long sum=0;
    
    puts("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        int iSquared = i * i; 
  
        int nextProduct = sum + iSquared;

        sum += nextProduct;

        printf("(%d * %d) = %d\n", i, i, iSquared);

    }

    printf("\nThe sum of the series is %ld\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

It's highly debatable if this is more user friendly honestly, but I still think it's more clear to have each step broken out logically especially when first trying to learn C++ or programming in general.

Comment: 1) Using floating point math for an integer problem is a weak approach.  2) `(double)` is not _required_.  It can quiet a warning.  OTOH, the warning is hinting that code is performing a questionable action.

Comment: I don't disagree my interpretation of user friendly is to explicitly call out the logical steps, so I was thinking the `pow()` call makes the squaring of i explicit but perhaps it would just be better kept as `i*i` to avoid unneeded casting.

Comment: Please note that, if neeeded (and it isn't), it should be `<math.h>` , not `<Math.h>`. You have also introduced an error aside with the variable `nextProduct`, the squared value is added twice. Sometimes storing intermediate steps of calculations into variables (possibly `const`, though) may increase readability, but in this case I'd argue it may be better to write a `square` function `long square(int x) { return (long)x * x; }`.

Comment: @Bob__ Oops thought I cut the `math.h` out thanks for the heads up. 
I wish SO had a move answer back to draft mode I didn't even think about that last night. I don't like leaving incorrect answers up, but I don't wanna delete my answer outright I'd rather come back and edit it when I have more time.

Comment: I'm not sure that this improves the readability, but regardless, this isn't correct: `int iSquared = i * i; int nextProduct = sum + iSquared; sum += nextProduct;` can be rewritten as `int iSquared = i * i; sum += sum + iSquared;` which can be rewritten as `sum = sum + sum + i*i;` which isn't the same as the original.

Comment: Not to mention that the temporary variables `iSquared` and `nextProduct` being `int` would cause overflow for higher input values.

Comment: @Bob__ ... or `long long square(int x) { return (long long)x * x; }`.